# Expected value of squared binomial variable

Tags: probability

I'm trying to arrive at the expected value of a square of binomial variable from the fundamental definition. Its from the last video explanation of expected value calculation of `X1^2` from here https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/165

Brief explanation:

$X_1$ is the number of heads from tossing a coin 3 times.

In the video $E(X_1^2)$ is arrived at by solving $Var(X_1) + \mu^2$ from the formula $Var(X_1) = E(X_1^2) - \mu^2$. The answer according to this approach is

> $3*1/4 + 3/2*3/2 = 12/4 = 3$

While I understand the solution given, I want to arrive at the answer using the basic definition of $E(X_1^2)$ as follows; can anyone pls. point out where I am wrong here

> $E(X_1^2) = E((x_1+x_2+x_3)^2) = E(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2) \quad\backslash\backslash\text{ as }E(2x_ix_j) = 0$
>
> $\implies E(x_1^2)+E(x_2^2)+E(x_3^2) = 0.5+0.5+0.5 = 3/2$

Comment: Why do you think $E\,x_i x_j = 0$?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 you are encouraged to use mathjax on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think that $\mathsf E(x_ix_j)=0$?

You may be conflating with the fact that $\mathsf {Cov}(x_i,x_j)=0$ for uncorrelated random variables, which includes independent random variables .

However, that means $\mathsf E(x_ix_j)-\mathsf E(x_i)\mathsf E(x_j)=0$.

So $\mathsf E(X^2)~{ = \sum_{i=1}^3\mathsf E(x_i^2) ~+~2\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 3}\mathsf E(x_ix_j) \\ = 3\,\mathsf E(x_1^2) ~+~6\,\mathsf E(x_1)\,\mathsf E(x_2) \\ = 3\cdot \tfrac 12 + 6\cdot\tfrac 14 \\ = 3}$

---

**Remark:**

More typically, this technique is used to *construct* the formula for variance of binomial distributions.

When $Y\sim\mathcal {Bin}(n,p)$ and using the indicators $(Y_i)_{i=1}^n$ for success in the $n$ iid Bernouli trials, we have:

$$\mathsf {Var}(Y) ~{= \mathsf E(Y^2) - \mathsf E(Y)^2 \\ = [n\mathsf E(Y_1^2)+n(n-1)\mathsf E(Y_1)^2]-[n^2\mathsf E(Y_1)^2] \\ = n(\mathsf E(Y_1^2)-\mathsf E(Y_1)^2) \\ = n(p-p^2) \\ = np(1-p)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables then $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$.